# Bootstrap jumbotron change height for smaller screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

Simple bootstrap jumbotron...

```
.jumbotron-page {
height:300px;
}
```

I need the height to change to 100px when on mobile/small devices so i get this...

```
.jumbotron-page {
height:100px;
}
```

I just can't get my media queries right to achieve this.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please include your media queries with the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your mobile devices have screen sizes less than ~700px

Include the following meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
```

And the media query:

```
@media all and (max-width: 700px)
{
    .jumbotron-page
    {
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use maximum-scale=1.  It ruins the web for those who need to be able to do pinch-zoom (around 30-40% of the population).

Comment: @Karlth why are you commenting on a post from 4 years ago?

Comment: @david Because old answers are still being used as guidance.  Maximum-scale ruins websites for a lot of people and is even ignored by for example Safari on iOS.